Can GPS live tracking log GPGLL strings in QGIS?
I am using QGIS MaidenHead in the field, with one laptop connected to a serial port GPS for ships location, and one laptop connected via serial port GPS for ‘package’ location underwater. The ships position logs GPGGA strings through the saved NMEA file (which is great!), but the ‘package’ position will not connect as it logs GPGLL strings. Any suggestions if we can’t change data strings?

GPSBabel development version can read Read/write GPGGA sentences. Then you can use this to connect to QGIS. https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_nmea.html https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html#loading-to-or-from-a-device
